# Oracle - convert char to date

Tags: sql, oracle, date, type-conversion

I try to convert a old time char(8) column to a new `time_conv` date column.

The String column have the following format:

Hour (0-99):Minute (0-59):Second (0:59)

For Example: 01:32:56

The following code does not work for me:

```
update teldat set time_conv=to_date(time,'hh24:mi:ss');
```

**Edit:**

```
CREATE TABLE teldat(
    datum       DATE,
    uhrzeit     CHAR(8),
    time        CHAR(8),
    teilnehmer  NUMBER(3),
    verbart     NUMBER(1),
    aufbauart   CHAR(3),
    ziel        VARCHAR(15));

alter table teldat add (time_conv date);

INSERT INTO TELDAT VALUES (to_date('04.08.2011'),'17:33 ', '00:00:40',10,9, 'K10', NULL); 
INSERT INTO TELDAT VALUES (to_date('04.08.2011'),'18:50 ', '00:01:41',13,9, 'K10', NULL); 
INSERT INTO TELDAT VALUES (to_date('04.08.2011'),'19:10 ', '00:02:17',21,1, 'G1 ', '01019012896****'); 
INSERT INTO TELDAT VALUES (to_date('04.08.2011'),'19:31 ', '00:11:01',10,9, 'K10', NULL); 
INSERT INTO TELDAT VALUES (to_date('04.08.2011'),'19:52 ', '00:09:47',20,1, 'G11', '077202****'); 
INSERT INTO TELDAT VALUES (to_date('04.08.2011'),'19:49 ', '10:07:02',21,1, 'G1 ', '01019012896****'); 
INSERT INTO TELDAT VALUES (to_date('04.08.2011'),'19:58 ', '00:02:41',21,1, 'G1 ', '01019012896****'); 
INSERT INTO TELDAT VALUES (to_date('04.08.2011'),'20:01 ', '00:02:31',21,1, 'G1 ', '01019012896****'); 
INSERT INTO TELDAT VALUES (to_date('05.08.2011'),'09:03 ', '00:03:02',11,9, 'K10', NULL); 
INSERT INTO TELDAT VALUES (to_date('05.08.2011'),'09:13 ', '00:03:31',10,1, 'G10', '071174****'); 
INSERT INTO TELDAT VALUES (to_date('05.08.2011'),'09:39 ', '00:06:45',13,1, 'G10', '0711707*****');
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't work for me"? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: No error message, something is wrong with my command... 

the output result in column time_conv is on every single row a date 01.06.15

Comment: Can you please share your table's definition and some sample data?

Comment: added sample code in main thread

Comment: The update statement is fine, it's just that `date` isn't the best type to store time (only) data. If you query this column in the correct format, you'll see it saves the data wanted - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/880ff/2

Comment: what's your recommendation for time only data?

Comment: Frankly, my recommendation is to not separate them - `datum` can hold both the date and the time.

Comment: Oracle doesn't have a data type to store _only_ a time.

Comment: In your case, it seems like "time"  is the duration of a connection. Using a number column that contains the duration in seconds seems like the most appropriate solution.

Comment: howto convert the column to seconds only?

Comment: See Gordon's answer for that...

Comment: Formatting. Removed thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert the value to seconds, then just use arithmetic:

```
select (to_number(substr(time, 1, 2)) * 60 * 60 +
        to_number(substr(time, 4, 2)) * 60 +
        to_number(substr(time, 7, 2))
       ) as seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me :)

```
  update teldat set time_conv=(to_number(substr(time, 1, 2)) * 60 * 60 +
        to_number(substr(time, 4, 2)) * 60 +
        to_number(substr(time, 7, 2))
       );
```

Thank you all guys!